# How to handle Exception Handling in Python

Tags: python

If a list_goods[i] item does not exist in all_keys variable which is a keys of dictionary, I am supposed to catch an exception and adds the item followed by a value "none" to a new dictionary variable. However my codes does not work. Appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction, Thanks!P.s I am not supposed to use If else in this assignment.

List and Dictionary in main method

```
 dict_q2 = {"vinegar": [120.0, 100], "ketchup": [950, 1000],"apples": [850,1100],"oranges": [1050, 0]
```

}

```
 list_q2 = ["ketchup","oranges","pear"]
```

Function to take in the above list and dict

```
def compute_unit_prices(dict_goods, list_goods):
#dict variable with name of good as key and unit prices as values. 
return_dict = {}
all_keys = dict_goods.keys()
i =0
#Try block
try:
  while (list_goods[i] in all_keys):
   goods_name = list_goods[i]
   storage = dict_goods[goods_name]
   results = storage[0] / storage[1]
   return_dict.update({goods_name:results})
   i = i+1

except KeyError as e:
    return_dict.update({goods_name:"none"})
# If zeroDivisionError is encountered, this block of code is used
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    results = -1
    return_dict.update({goods_name:results})
# This block of code works if errors other than the above two occurs
except:
    return_dict = {}
finally:
    print(return_dict)
```

Comment: Why are you "supposed to throw an exception"? Why can't you simply take remedial action if `list_goods[i]` is not in `all_keys`?

Comment: There are a lot of issues here. First of all, `goods_name` variable may be undefined if exception is thrown here: `while (list_goods[i] in all_keys):`. Also, if an exception is thrown, you are not changing the value of `i` so you'll keep going to the same value over and over. Finally, `except KeyError as e` - here variable `e` is not used for anything, why have it at all?

Comment: by the way it might help if you tell what the problem is. Surprizingly your code, even though it is incorrect worked on my pc. `{'ketchup': 0.95, 'oranges': -1}`

Comment: The problem faced is that, the output u achieved is part of the answer. however im supposed to have an additional 'pear': none. so for pear that is not in dict_q2, its value will be automatically set to none. I have tried using key error exception but to no avail, as I am not supposed to use If-else statements.

Comment: I see. Check my answer.

Comment: Hey serge! your solution works. Inserting try and except inside the for loop works!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

1. You was told to make sure that your code throws exceptions (run-time error) and catches them with `try`. And yet your code avoids iterating over the missing dictionary keys due to a peculiar `while` loop condition. Which is wrong on many levels. Better refactor to `for i in range(len(list_goods))` loop. Otherwise `while` exits the loop on the first key out of the dictionary, so the `KeyError` exception does not have a single chance to occur. Also you risk `i` running out of the boundaries.
2. Move exception handling inside the loop. Otherwise the first exception will terminate the loop, and you want to process each and every element of the list.
3. Remove `finally`. You do not need it any more. Just print the result outside of the loop.

PS. Actually `for good in list_goods` is more pythonic, use that if you comfortable enough with python loop, but you will need to do more changes inside the loop.

Comment: Why not use `finally`? `Else` only executes if `try` block is successful, but you'd want to print resulting dictionary in any case, hence `finally` is appropriate.